# Llamar a un stored procedure desde Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estoy usando stored procedure, SQL Server, EF (code first). Tengo un stored procedure creado en la base de datos y quiero llamarlo desde mi código.

Stored procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE uspCreateLocal
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@Direccion varchar(100),
@Nombre varchar(80),
@Fijo varchar(9),
@Celular varchar(9),
@Administrador int

AS

BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
INSERT INTO Locales (Direccion, Nombre, Fijo, Celular, Administrador) 
    VALUES(@Direccion, @Nombre, @Fijo, @Celular, @Administrador)
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS  LocalId 
END                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
GO
```

Desde mi código deseo llamarlo

```
public void InsertOrUpdate(Local entity)
    {
        using (var context = new PosContext())
        {
            if (entity.LocalId == default(int))
            {
                bool exist = Exist(o => o.Nombre == entity.Nombre);
                if(exist)
                    throw new ArgumentException("El Local, que intenta registrar ya existe.");
                else
                {
                    context.Locales.Add(entity);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

Voy a reemplazar la parte del Add por el store. ¿Cómo debo de llamarlo y enviarle los parámetros?

Lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera:

```
public void InsertOrUpdate(Local entity)
    {
        using (var context = new PosContext())
        {
            if (entity.LocalId == default(int))
            {
                bool exist = Exist(o => o.Nombre == entity.Nombre);
                if(exist)
                    throw new ArgumentException("El Local, que intenta registrar ya existe.");
                else
                {
                    //context.Locales.Add(entity);
                    //context.SaveChanges();
                    DbModelBuilder modelBuilder = new DbModelBuilder();
                    modelBuilder.Entity<Local>()
                        .MapToStoredProcedures(s =>
                        s.Insert(i => i.HasName("uspCreateLocal")
                        .Parameter(b => b.Direccion, "Direccion")
                        .Parameter(b => b.Nombre, "Nombre")
                        .Parameter(b => b.Fijo, "Fijo")
                        .Parameter(b => b.Celular, "Celular")
                        .Parameter(b => b.Administrador, "Administrador")));
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
```

No logro guardar en la db el nuevo registro porque está fuera del contexto. ¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando me ha tocado ejecutar procedimientos almacenados desde Entity Framework, lo he hecho usando `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()`. En tu caso, se vería algo así:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
    "exec uspCreateLocal @Direccion, @Nombre, @Fijo, @Celular, @Administrador",
    new SqlParameter("@Direccion", entity.Direccion),
    new SqlParameter("@Nombre", entity.Nombre),
    new SqlParameter("@Fijo", entity.Fijo),
    new SqlParameter("@Celular", entity.Celular),
    new SqlParameter("@Administrador", entity.Administrador));
```

**Comentario adicional:**

Sin importar la forma como ejecutes el procedimiento almacenado, porque no se trata de un EF entity, la ejecución se aplica de inmediato a la base de datos. No hay necesidad de llamar `SaveChanges()` como se hace con las modificaciones usuales a los entities.

Comment: que alegría que me respondieras estaba horas probando ya había hecho uno parecido pero no era el correcto, funciono excelente, es un ejemplo de muestra le puedo pasar un index al store me refiero a los stor que tienen varias operacones dentro, se puede hacer si estubieran involucradas varias entidades(tablas) haria una clase donde  pondría las propiedades de las entidades involucradas

Comment: bueno si estuviese relacionada mis entidades y en este caso lo están por navegabilidad debería mostrarme otros propiedades de otras entidades relacionadas

Answer (score 2):

Esta es la forma como los llamo, tenga en cuenta que el Dbset es generico en el caso suyo debe llamarlo para un dbset especifico que es como se suele usar, retorna los queries en un Dictionary

```
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using MySql.Data.Entity;
  using System.Data.Common;
  using System.Data.Entity;
  using DbManager.Mensajeria;
  using DbManager.Shared;
  using ClassLibraryLog;
  using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
  using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Data.SqlClient;
  using System.Collections;
  using System.Reflection;

  namespace DbManager
  {
   public class DbManager<T> : DbContext where T : class
  {
    public DbSet<T> listItems { get; set; }
    //private object objType;

    public DbManager(string context) : base(context)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<DbManager<T>>(null);
    }

  public virtual Dictionary<string, object> ExecuteStoreProcedureWithResultDictionary(string NameStoreProcedure, Dictionary<string, object> Parameters)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> Values = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        try
        {
            var cmd = Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = NameStoreProcedure;
            Database.Connection.Open();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> x in Parameters)
            {

                var param = cmd.CreateParameter();
                param.ParameterName = string.Format("@{0}", x.Key);
                param.Value = x.Value;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

            }
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            do
            {
                try
                {
                    //  values = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.Translate<T>(reader, "listItems", MergeOption.AppendOnly).ToList();
                    bool findValues = false;

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        T data = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
                        data.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().ForEach(x =>
                        {
                            if (!x.GetMethod.IsVirtual)
                            {
                                if (reader.GetOrdinal(x.Name) >= 0)
                                {
                                    object value = reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal(x.Name));
                                    Values.Add(x.Name, value);
                                    findValues = true;
                                    //  values.Add(data);
                                }
                            }

                        });
                    }
                    if(findValues)
                        break;
                    // reader.

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    ClassLogger.LogMsg(LogLevel.ERROR, this.GetType().Name, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, e.ToString(), true);
                    return null;
                }

            } while (reader.NextResult());


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ClassLogger.LogMsg(LogLevel.ERROR, this.GetType().Name, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, e.ToString(), true);
            return null;
        }
        return Values;

    }
}
```

Comment: No me convence la forma como lo implementas

Comment: @Pedro Avila varias cosas la primera es que no es muy constructivo el comentario respecto a lo convincente que sea o no, lo otro es que como lo dije en la respuesta este es para un dbset generico, ya que la intencion era consultar cualquier tipo de datos y poderlo devolver partiendo de cualquier tipo de parametro, ya si necesita acoplarlo a una clase especifica

Comment: @PedroÁvila para tratar de ejecutar un store sobre un objeto especifico puede tratar de usar ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.Translate<T>(reader, "listItems", MergeOption.AppendOnly).ToList() pero ud tendria que saber que devuelve el store y que equivalga a un entity

Comment: voy a modificar la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

de esta manera implemento un SP, desde C#, usando EF.

```
   private void btn_EliminarSeleccionDelGrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ProductosEF _bdVentas = new ProductosEF();

            if (MessageBox.Show("¿Desea eliminar el producto seleccionado?", "¡Advertencia!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                string EliminarSeleccionDelGrid = dgvProductos.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

                _bdVentas.DeleteProduct(EliminarSeleccionDelGrid);
            }

            _bdVentas.SaveChanges();

            CargarGrid();
        {
```

Toma en cuenta: que el "***DeleteProduct***" es el nombre del SP.

espero sea de ayuda, para una futura visita a esta pregunta.